# How to catch task failure on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

Google App Engine provides us with task queues ([task queue reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)). I use a push queue configured to retry failed tasks 4 times. I would like to handle a case when task fails completely, all 4 tries haven't succeed.

Is there is a way to handle full task failure with taskqueue API? Kind of post mortem handler.

```
   <queue>
    <name>my-queue</name>
    <rate>100/s</rate>
    <bucket-size>100</bucket-size>
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-retry-limit>4</task-retry-limit>
        <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
        <max-backoff-seconds>200</max-backoff-seconds>
    </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is [answered](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/-_P7jjwGoV8) on GAE Forum.

Alejandro Gonzalez proposed to read number of tries from special GAE header and handle everything else on one's own.

```
String retryCount = request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount");
```